# What is the Maximum length that a Windows Registry Key name can be?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-xp, registry

I'm writing a very long registry Key name (it's a list of programs for a combined uninstall) and I think it's too big.

What's the max size the key can be (in characters) ?
(The smallest maximum among Win xp, vista, 7 since it'll need to work on all of them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256986), it is 255 characters.

Answer (score 20):

**Key Name:** 255 characters
**Value name:** 16,383 characters
**Value:** Available memory (latest format)
or 1 MB (standard format)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Actually, according to the link you sent it is key name: 255, value name: 16383, and actual value: 1 megabyte.

Answer (score 7):

here's a key that's longer than 255:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\DeviceClasses{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}##?#STORAGE#VOLUME#_??_USBSTOR#DISK&VEN_LEXAR&PROD_USB_FLASH_DRIVE&REV_1100#AANL1B891R5GCDV6&0#{53F56307-B6BF-11D0-94F2-00A0C91EFB8B}#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}#

I found this when I was writing a tool to search all keys in the registry.  I created a buffer that was 256 which caused a stack corruption exception.

When I tried to view this key using regedit I noticed it shows an arrow indicating there are subkeys but won't respond when clicked on. I only guess at the final '#' key because other keys in that area end with it.

When I doubled the buffer everything went smoothly.

Comment: It's an API bug. The documentation says key length limit is 255, but RegCreateKeyEx accepts 256, and the null terminator doesn't count. So, 257. Oops.

Comment: MSDN said that one single key node name' length should not be larger than 255, not the full path. Also, your key's length is still not larger than 255.

Comment: @Zatronium I also found it later, registry editor allow a key name with 256 valid characters, not including the null terminator.

Comment: @賈可Jacky "not the full path" this is not true, see Ben's answer (but apparently it's incorrect; I also have a similar key of around 300 characters, maybe these can be created through shorter symlinks?)

Comment: @SWdV No, MSDN never said that a full sub key path should not exceed 255 characters. If you found that there is a limit, it it still a bug of API of ANSI version, try to use Unicode versions, like RegOpenKeyExW rather than RegOpenKeyExA.

Comment: @SWdV At least in the Windows 2000 leaked source code, both `RegOpenKeyExA` and `RegCreateKeyExA` converts the input sub key string to the **StaticUnicodeString** in the **TEB** structure, which contains only 261 characters in size, and then call the Unicode versions.

Comment: Just tested on Windows 10, no length limit when either ANSI version or Unicode version is called.

Comment: @賈可Jacky Oh weird. Still, the linked MS Docs page says "255 characters. The key name includes the absolute path of the key in the registry, always starting at a base key, for example, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE."

Comment: @SWdV 255 is the maximun length of a single node name in a sub key path, for example HKLM\<255-chars>\<255-chars>\...

Comment: @賈可Jacky I guess I'm reading it wrong then but I'm not sure how you can read it any other way